# Nuclearity of the free product of C* algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis

Let $A, B$ be unital $C^*$ algebras and $A\star B$ their unital (universal) free product. Assume that $A$ and $B$ are nuclear. When can we say that $A\star B$ is nuclear? I know that it can happen, e.g. $\mathbb{C}^{2}\star \mathbb{C}^{2}=\mathrm{C}^*(\mathbb{Z}_2\star \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is nuclear as $\mathbb{Z}_2\star \mathbb{Z}_2$ is amenable, but on the other hand $\mathrm{C}^*(\mathbb{Z})\star \mathrm{C}^*( \mathbb{Z})=\mathrm{C}^*(F_2)$ is not nuclear.

I would be also interested in an analogous question for the reduced free products.

Comment: I have found some partial answers: 
The universal free product of finite dimensional $C^*$ algebras is never nuclear except some special cases "Exactness of universal free products of finite dimensional $C^*$ algebras with amalgamation" - Duncan.

The reduced free product preserves nuclearity provided one of the states is pure (this is Theorem 4.8.7 in Brown-Ozawa "C*-algebras and finite dimensional approximations"). I am still interested though in the case where both states are not pure.